# How to Make a Date Column in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with the below format:

[image]

I need to split into tow columns: 1) date (year and month) and 2) values

I have written the below code but returns dimension error:

```
date_range = pd.date_range(start = '1952-01-1' , end = '2015-01-01' , freq = 'M')
dateFrame = pd.DataFrame({'date':date_range,'val': values.values.tolist()})
```

Comment: `df.melt('year', var_name='month')`

Comment: post an example of what the output should look like, please

Comment: melt function works.